# Symfony: paths of css, js and images after upload

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently developing my first project on symfony.
I just put the whole project online. And all the paths css, js and images are wrong. I mean, the "http + domain name" is missing.
That's how I call them : 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/framework/css/main.css') }}"/>`

Does somone know what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Which Symfony version do you use?

Comment: The ftp hadn't transfer the file framework, that's it ! resolved topic :)